# Range Slider with no maximum value

Tags: jquery, angular, slider, angular5, jquery-ui-slider

I'm making a range slider with ng2-ion-range-slider Angular 5
But I want make a slider with no maximum value which is infinite slider
Any recommendations?

Comment: So if you're half way on the slider, it's half of infinity?

Comment: I set a minimum value of my slider but I want to put the maximum value to infinite value which is mean scrolling it to endless

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: Trying to explain that's literally impossible with slider. If maximum value is infinity, then scrolling to right will almost be like not scrolling at all. the best you can get away with is either having a value input field, with a joystick like actions to swipe/toggle left or right to decrease/increase value. Or try to do what Excel does, created limited range, and slowly increase it as user gets past certain point.